# How to convert the dictionary with one key and a tuple as the key value into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, count

I have a dictionary like this.

`dict={'good': (5, 3, 5), 'nice': (6, 0, 0), 'very': (8, 3, 4), 'not': (2, 0, 1)}`

I need to convert it into a dataframe such that it looks like this:

```
Variable     Positive Neutral Negative
good           5       3       5
nice           6       0       0
very           8       3       4
not            2       0       1
```

I tried using:

`pd.DataFrame(dict).melt()`

But it is giving me the data frame in the following form:

```
Variable Value

good      5
good      3
good      5
nice      6
nice      0
nice      0
...
```

Please help me get the required output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an index to `pd.DataFrame` and then take `T`ranpose:

```
pd.DataFrame(d, index=["Positive", "Neutral", "Negative"]).T
```

or `swapaxes`:

```
pd.DataFrame(d, index=["Positive", "Neutral", "Negative"]).swapaxes(0, 1)
```

where `d` is your dictionary,

to get

```
      Positive  Neutral  Negative
good         5        3         5
nice         6        0         0
very         8        3         4
not          2        0         1
```